# best way to inject request header in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm developing an api that post a simple class to a database and i'm using asp.net web api and Ninject. Clients of this api, are making this api a request with headers

`username: xx and password: yy`

So every in every method i have to check if username and password is correct. I know this is not true way to do that i can use BasicAuth. OAuth exc. but i have to in that way.

My question is, it is possible that i can inject the logic of reading request header to a gloabl variable so i can stop repating myself.

The simple logic that i'm using:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(Sale saleRecord)
   {
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   var username = request.Headers["username"];
   var password = request.Headers["password"];
   if(username=="xx" && password=="yy")
   {//Logic here} 
   }
```

In Mvc we can override `OnActionExecuting()` method and check those headers but in web api i cant override it.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Action Filters like in MVC in web api too and solve reading common and header info from the request.

https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/

I am not very familiar with Ninject but in the above article it does show how to do IoC for Action filters , I use Structuremaps and I do through property injection in case of Action Filters/Attributes.